# I'm trying to do comparision of two arrays by using this code, but I'm getting error: java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

```
@Test(priority=4)
    public void content(){

        String[] x = {"Home", "Chatter", "Campsites", "Campsite Reservations", "Countries", "Table", "SPP Email Domain" };


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'salesforceIdentityAppLauncherHeader')]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Content']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
        WebElement Lightning = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Content']"));
        boolean displayedStatus = Lightning.isDisplayed();
        Assert.assertEquals(displayedStatus, true);
        List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='slds-truncate'][contains(@data-aura-rendered-by,':0;p')]"));
        System.out.println(text.size());
        List<String> all_elements = new ArrayList<>();  
        for(int i=0; i<text.size();i++){
        all_elements.add(text.get(i).getText());
        }
        System.out.println(all_elements);
        Assert.assertEquals(all_elements, x);
```

but the error is:

> FAILED: content
>   java.lang.AssertionError: expected [[Ljava.lang.String;@25be7b63] but found [[Home, Chatter, Campsites, Campsite Reservations, Countries, Table, SPP Email Domain]]

Comment: which line this error comes from in  your code?

Comment: Error should be the last line. Trying to assert whether a `String[]` equals a `List<String>` seems a bad idea ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `List<String>` to `String[]`, using

```
String[] converted_all_elements = all_elements.toArray(new String[0]);
```

And then try this,

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals( all_elements, x );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because you are comparing a string array with ArrayList.

Declare your 'x' as ArrayList and it should work:

List x =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Home", "Chatter", "Campsites", "Campsite Reservations", "Countries", "Table", "SPP Email Domain"));

Comment: I'm using below code using Testng, getting error Null Pointer exception

Comment: public static WebDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
 public void Login() {
    WebDriver driver = new chromeDriver();
    driver.get("xxx");
    driver.findElement(By.name("xx")).sendKeys("xxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("xx")).sendKeys("xxx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
   
}   
@Test(priority=2)
public void Marketingtab(){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'salesforceIdentityAppLauncherHeader')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Marketing']")).click();

Comment: Error: FAILED: Marketingtab java.lang.NullPointerException at salesforce.Login_SF.Marketingtab(Login_SF.java:41) at

Comment: I cant make out much from your code,but for sure, some object is null that you are trying to access, please debug and check ,what exactly is null and why.